# C#. Inner join to dataGrid, wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

In order to display my Linq query in a dataGrid, I use a wrappe as you see in the following code, but it does't work.

I still have this error `cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to ViewModels.ConsultInvoiceViewModel.SubInvoice'`

And my Anonymous type is
'a is new {Invoice Invoice, string description, string unit1}

Why?

```
        private void GetSub()
        {
            var invoice = Selected;
            var invs = (from i in ctx.Invoices
                        join p in ctx.products on i.refSupp equals p.refsup
                        join u in ctx.units on p.unit equals u.idunit
                        where i.suppInvNumber == invoice.suppInvNumber
                        select new { 
                           Invoice = i,
                           description = p.description,
                           unit1 = u.unit1
                       });

             Products.Clear();
             if (invs != null)
                foreach (var inv in invs)
                {
                    Products.Add(inv); // error
                }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SubInvoice> _products;

        public ObservableCollection<SubInvoice> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return _products;
            }
            set
            {
                _products = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Products");
            }
        }

        public class SubInvoice
        {
            public Invoice invoice;
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string unit1 { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create strong typed collection

```
...
select new SubInvoice{
               Invoice = i,
               description = p.description,
               unit1 = u.unit1
          });
```

And make `invoice` property

```
public Invoice Invoice {get; set;}
```